# Python v3.4.3 ftp connection refused

Tags: python, ftp

I am trying to download a file from an ftp server, but have been unable to connect. Here is the code framework and error message. What am I doing wrong? The site's user guide gives instructions to login as "anonymous" with your email address as the password.

```
server = "ftp://ftp.sec.gov/"
directory = "edgar/data/"
filename = "nameoffile.txt"

from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP(server, 'anonymous', 'myemail@gmail.com') #Set server address
```

Then this pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
ftp = FTP(server)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/ftplib.py", line 118, in __init__
self.connect(host)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/ftplib.py", line 153, in connect
source_address=self.source_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 512, in create_connection
raise err
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 503, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get the same error as you, however, FTP does not support URLs as a way of defining the remote FTP server. Instead it requires a host name or IP address:

```
>>> from ftplib import FTP
>>> ftp = FTP('ftp.sec.gov', 'anonymous', 'myemail@gmail.com')
>>> ftp.dir()
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root          369 Nov  2  2009 README.html
-rw-r--r--   2 root     root          749 Aug 15  2000 README.txt
d--x--x--x   2 root     wheel        4096 Jul 30  1998 bin
drwxrwxr-x  15 1024     106          4096 Aug  6 02:01 edgar
d--x--x--x   2 root     wheel        4096 Aug 14  2000 etc
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           33 Nov 16  2012 index.htm -> /usr/local/web/index.nobrowse.htm
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root            6 Nov 16  2012 pub -> /edgar
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root           86 Sep  3  2010 robots.txt
d--x--x--x   3 root     root         4096 Oct 26  2000 usr
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     bin          4096 Oct 14  1999 y2kforms
```

Comment: I tried to adjust based on your advice, but still receive an error. The first two errors, occuring on lines 118 & 153, persist, but I've left them off for brevity sake.  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 494, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 533, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Comment: So now it's a different error. Your system can not resolve the host name to an IP address. Try using the IP address, `162.138.208.11`. If that works, you will need to figure out why Python can't resolve the host name. Can you access the FTP site using the URL in your question from the same machine using your browser?

Comment: Works fine when I use the IP address...I'm also able to access the FTP site using my browser and the URL above.

Comment: Does your browser use a proxy?

Comment: Was able to make it work by switching my network proxy setting from passive to active. Thanks.